# Specializing only nested template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, typename, dependent-name

I have following template:

```
template<typename FirstParam>
struct First
{
    template<typename SecondParam>
    struct Second;
};
```

Example specialization:

```
template<typename T> class D {};

template<>
template<>
struct First<C1>::Second<C1::C2>
{
    typedef D<C1::C2> type;
};
```

This is case when both classes are specialized at the same time. But is there possible to specialize only second class?

Something like:

```
template<typename OuterParam>
template<>
struct Outer<OuterParam>::Inner<typename OuterParam::C2>
{
    typedef E<typename OuterParam::C2> type;
};
```

(Yes, I also need second param to be inner class of the first.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. §14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p16, emphasis added:

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class
>   template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the
>   member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, **except that the declaration shall not explicitly
>   specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates
>   are not explicitly specialized as well.**

You can use a "partial" specialization and `std::is_same` instead:

```
template<typename FirstParam>
struct First
{
    template<typename SecondParam, bool = std::is_same<typename FirstParam::C2,
                                                       SecondParam>::value>
    struct Second;

    template<class T>
    struct Second<T, true> { 
    };
};
```